# alias su='su -' in .kshrc

Tags: ksh, openbsd

I'm on OpenBSD 5.8, new to ksh and I put the string

```
alias su='su -'
```

in my .kshrc file as the only line. After logging in via ssh

```
alias su
```

gives me

```
su alias not found
```

and

```
$(cat .kshrc)
```

gives me

```
-' alias not found
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `alias su='su - '`.oh, that's not it. `ksh` isn't sourcing your .rc. It needs to be put in `$ENV` by `ssh` at login.

Comment: okay. how do I make ssh put it in $ENV?

Comment: now I put ENV=$HOME/.kshrc in .profile. Is that what you meant?

Comment: actually yes. it still wont source it if EUID and UID dont align - but they should.

Comment: yes they are. if you make it an answer I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interactive `ksh` sources the file named in the environment variable `$ENV` at startup if its EUID and UID match and `$ENV` - after being subjected to shell expansions - evaluates to the name of a readable file. And so if `alias`es specified in your `~/.kshrc` are not loaded at runtime, then it is probably because it is not being sourced, and that is probably because it is not in `$ENV`.

So your solution could be to put it in a file sourced before that - *(such as `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` for `ssh` login shells)*.

```
echo 'ENV=~/.kshrc' >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: @StefanBerger - meh. votes are nice - but solving problems is better. and anyway - always be suspicious of answers with a *lot* of votes - especially *new* answers. they only get that way if everyone instantly agrees with them - and that only usually happens for stuff that is either *common knowledge* or stuff that those that don't know any better commonly *believe*.